# Using stored procedure to alter multiple columns within a table

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to create a stored procedure for altering a dataset to save a user manually changing the datatypes.

My code is similar to:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_ALTERTABLECOLUMNS]
AS

ALTER TABLE 
x
ALTER COLUMN 
A TINYINT NOT NULL;

ALTER TABLE 
x
ALTER COLUMN 
B TINYINT NOT NULL;


ALTER TABLE 
x
ALTER COLUMN 
C SMALLINT NOT NULL;


ALTER TABLE 
x
ALTER COLUMN 
D DATE NOT NULL;


ALTER TABLE 
x
ALTER COLUMN
E DATE NOT NULL;
```

It fails to carry out the desired outcome when executed at present. I also get an error when I attempted to put `go` between each `alter` statement.

Comment: *"It fails to carry out the desired outcome when executed at present."* so what *does* it do? What is its goal? *Why* do you need to do this at all (seems like a major [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info))? `GO` isn't a T-SQL command, it's interpreted by the IDE (such as SSMS, `sqlcmd`, ADS) as a batch separator.

Comment: Unsure if you're just having a bad day buddy. I have a very similar data set being imported regularly and by people who aren't overly familiar with SQL. The idea is that each time they import it they are able to run a 1 line procedure rather than a page of code (There are 46 tables total). Is this a silly question? I'm fairly new to SQL but thought it would be a good idea in principle. . .

Comment: Altering the definition of a table, in a stored procedure, doesn't make sense; a table's definition should be well defined and stable. If a table's definition is in flux, then that suggests a much larger, underlying problem, and hence why these seems like an XY Problem. Without knowing what the real goal is we can't really help you here. As you don't describe what it currently does, and why it isn't the desired behaviour, we can't even help you with what you *are* trying to do. But fixing the underlying problem is likely what you need to do here, what ever that is. If you explain, we can help.

Comment: I think you're right. My original goal was to have a procedure that automatically altered a table on a one-off basis to reformat them with the desired data types. My problem is that my procedure created and ran without effecting the changes (ie. the data types changing from nvarchar to bigint etc). I was hoping to use this procedure repeatably for each different import. I believe I was missing a bit of clarity in my code which the person below left. Thanks for the suggestions though, will take  read up on the XY problem.

Comment: *"My problem is that my procedure created and ran without effecting the changes"* if this were the case, you would have received an error, which means we need to know the error. Either the statements ran, and the table's definition was changed, or (one of) the statements failed, the table's definition was not changed, and you received an error. If the latter, we need to know what that error was. I *suspect* it was a conversion error (perhaps on the `date` columns), which is why storing data in the wrong data type is a bad idea. `varchar` isn't a "one size fits all" data type.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with the code you posted.  eg this works fine.

```
drop table if exists x
go
create table x(id int identity primary key, a varchar(20), b varchar(20))
insert into x(a,b) values ('1','2'),('2','4')
go

Create or Alter PROC [dbo].[USP_ALTERTABLECOLUMNS]
AS
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE 
    x
    ALTER COLUMN 
    A TINYINT NOT NULL;

    ALTER TABLE 
    x
    ALTER COLUMN 
    B TINYINT NOT NULL;
END
go
exec [USP_ALTERTABLECOLUMNS]
go
select * from x
```

Comment: But, if the values in the table aren't valid for the datatype (such as if you tried to change column `b` to a `date`) it would fail. Of course, this is merely conjecture in the absence of details of what "isn't" working.